# who recommend me a professional computer vision web site so i can ask question in it

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision

who recommend me a professional  computer vision web site so i can  ask question in it.
thanks a lot

Comment: This site answers questions related to the development of CV applications.

Comment: In reality the question is valid.  Personally I don't think SO has gotten a lot of play except from the most populous developer communities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com).

Comment: waul ! I come to the right place but i didn't know. thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This site is as good as any - I'm sure CV experts read and answer questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: waul ! I come to the right place but i didn't know. thank you a lot.